# Is there a oracle hint to execute the where clauses in a specific order?

Tags: oracle, indexing, optimizer-hints

Consider the following two queries on a table where datecolumn is indexed -

```
Q1: select * from table where datecolumn > sysdate - 5;
Q2: select * from table where datecolumn > sysdate - 5 and datecolumn < sysdate - 1;
```

Q1 uses the index. But, Q2 somehow does a full table scan. Is it because oracle somehow chooses to execute "datecolumn < sysdate - 1" first ? In that case, is there a way to enforce order of execution of where clauses involving one column ?

Comment: First thing to do when encountering this sort of thing is to get explain plans for both queries. This will help to determine the actual cause of the plan change. *Then*, you might use one or more of the techniques given in the answers below - but for better reasons than "it seems to work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify an index hint, something like this:

```
select /*+ INDEX (table datecolumn_ix)*/ 
       * 
  from table 
  where datecolumn > sysdate - 5 and datecolumn < sysdate - 1;
```

See [Oracle Index Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is the `index` [hint](http://psoug.org/reference/hints.html).

```
/*+ INDEX(table index_name) */
```

But, in your case maybe is better to collect statistics of your table.

Use [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('schema','table')](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm) procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't guarantee by default that your tables will be joining in the same order as you mentioned, thus you may use these hints:

1. **ordered**
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5555
   It will join your tables in the same order as you mentioned in *where* statement
2. **leading**
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5730
   you may specify the join orders of your tables

   ```sql
   select /*+ leading (c b a) */
     a.*
   from
     tablea a
     , tableb b
     , tablec c
   where
     a.some_id = b.some_id
     and c.some_id = b.other_id
   ```

   Also, for your Q2 you may try the `between` option
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm